# What is interval for DAY_OF_MONTH for setRepeatingAlarm(); (Android)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an Alarm set in AlarmManager in Android.  it is a setInexactRepeatingAlarm() that should go off the same DAY_OF_MONTH.

I want it to go off on May 21st, June 21st, July 21st etc.

What is the interval to figure this out?  IS this even possible since some months have different days?

```
 am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), i, pendingIntent);
```

Where "i" is the interval formula I need to post.  For example, to set it once a day, it would be 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

What would once a month bee o the exact same calendar day?  Is this even possible?  If not, how is this accomplished?

Comment: Please post some code. I have an idea of what you're trying to say, but it's not clear without actually seeing what's going on.

Comment: Added and updated post as requested.

Comment: Looking through the documentation for AlarmManager, I don't believe it's possible to schedule it for a "once a month" interval, at least not without using something other than AlarmManager. Don't quote me on this though, because I haven't worked with AlarmManager all that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you're SOL on this one.

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) it's implied that the only intervals that inexact repeating alarms recognize are enumerated in the `AlarmManager` object:

> Available inexact recurrence intervals recognized by `setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)`: `INTERVAL_DAY`, `INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES`, `INTERVAL_HALF_DAY`, `INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR`, `INTERVAL_HOUR`.

Also, all alarms are unregistered when the device is power-cycled so the likelihood of your alarm ever going off (a month straight of on-time?) is probably low.

Perhaps you're approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: Yeah, I just came to this conclusion as well.  I am attempting this now with a regular "set" alarm (non-repeating).  Not sure where to go with that but someone is doing this I know so its work that way.